# How do I separate a number length into single digits to then use in mathematical operation?

Tags: javascript

So I'm new to coding in Javascript, so I'm working on Code Wars and was given the problem:

{A Narcissistic Number (or Armstrong Number) is a positive number which is the sum of its own digits, each raised to the power of the number of digits in a given base. In this Kata, we will restrict ourselves to decimal (base 10).

For example, take 153 (3 digits), which is narcissistic:

```
1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153
```

and 1652 (4 digits), which isn't:

```
1^4 + 6^4 + 5^4 + 2^4 = 1 + 1296 + 625 + 16 = 1938
```

The Challenge:

Your code must return true or false (not 'true' and 'false') depending upon whether the given number is a Narcissistic number in base 10. This may be True and False in your language, e.g. PHP.}

I wrote a code that for me makes sense, and passes some of the tests, but obviously being a bit new to this I did something wrong if someone can just let me know so I can better learn and understand what to properly do for a problem like this.

```
function narcissistic(value) {
    if (value != Number(value)) {
        return "Please enter a number!"
    } else {
        let counter = 0;
        let digits = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (value[i] === 0) {
                value.splice[i, 1];
                counter += 1;
                digits.push(i);
            }
        }
        if (value == digits ** value.length) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn the number into a string
2. Establish the length of the string as the exponent
3. Iterate through the digits in the string, accumulating the digit operation
4. Return the result of an `===` comparison to the original value.

So:

```js
    function narc(n) {
      const nstr = String(n), exp = nstr.length;
      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < exp; ++i) sum += nstr[i] ** exp;
      return n === sum;
    }


    console.log(narc(153));
    console.log(narc(1652));
```

Comment: Thank you, why didn't you have to surround sum += nstr[i] ** exp in curly brackets?

Comment: @Phrogsss `for`-loops' bodies are a statement. You can use a block statement (the curly brackets), a single statement, or even an empty statement (just a semicolon) as its body. Using a single statement or a block statement consisting of a single statement is effectively the same.

Comment: @Phrogsss if you prefer using `{ }` that's totally fine. In a simple case like this, my opinion is that it's clearer without them, but that's just my opinion and many upstanding members of the community would disagree.